# Mule ESB 3.7 CE adding a supporting project to main project

Tags: java, maven, mule, mule-studio

In Mule Studio 3.4 CE I've kept common code (DB connections etc) in a separate project (let's say platform). So any new project that I need to work on (lets call it NewProject)I would just go into Java Build Path for NewProject and add platform project to the Build path. This would ensure that when the project is built all the class files in that project would be placed under the bin folder in the required folder structure. Has this been revoked in the newer versions of Mule or is there a different way of doing this apart from writing a Maven script?

Comment: Why not simply trying it out? Simply download the newer version of Mule and AnyPoint Studio, and use a local virtual machine or test environment.

Comment: I've been trying to do it. The old method doesn't seem to work. Exporting a ZIP for deployment to Mule standalone doesn't contain the files from the supporting project. Research seems to drive me towards Maven. But don't want to have to have to setup a Maven build just because of this.

Comment: I think a Maven build is the way to go. It may seems more complicated at first glance, but what you describe is a very basic Maven usage. You'll probably just have to mavenize with Studio, add your dependency and run _mvn package_.